# How do I prevent a char input from affecting an int variable

Tags: c++

I have a loop that is looking for an int between 1 and 100. If the user enters a letter, the loop just goes crazy. How can I keep chars and ints separate? more details, more details, more details, more details

```
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
const int GUESSES = 5;                // The user gets 5 guesses, that never changes
int randomNumber = -1;                // Initializing the random number
int guessesRemaining = GUESSES;       // Initializing the guesses remaining
int userGuess = -1;                   // Initializing the user guess variable

srand(time(0));                       // srand is using the time function to generate a random number
randomNumber = rand() % 100 + 1;      // rand is using the modulus operator to divide the ms by 100 then adds 1 to the solution

// original instructions for the user
cout << "Welcome to the number guessing game. The computer will select a number between 1";
cout << "and 100. It is your job to guess this secret number. You are allowed 5 guesses.\n\n";

do
{
    //cout << randomNumber;
    // user prompt
    cout << "Please enter a number between 1 and 100: ";

    // user input
    cin >> userGuess;

    // if the users guess is less than 100 and greater than 0
    if (userGuess < 100 && userGuess > 0)
    {
        // if user answers correctly
        if (userGuess == randomNumber)
        {
            switch (guessesRemaining)
            {
            case 5:
                cout << "\nHoly crap! That's amazing! One shot, one kill!\n";
                break;
            case 4:
                cout << "\nWow, you're pretty good! You got it in two guesses!\n";
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "\nNot bad. You got it in three guesses.\n";
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "\nMan, that was a close one! You had one guess left.\n";
                break;
            case 1:
                cout << "\nBy the skin of your teeth! You got it on your last guess!!\n";
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
        // if user does NOT answer correctly and still has guesses remaining
        else if (--guessesRemaining > 0 && userGuess != randomNumber)
        {
            // notifies user guess is too high and displays remaining guesses.
            if (userGuess > randomNumber)
            {
                cout << "\nYour guess is too high, please try again. You have " << guessesRemaining << " guesses left.\n";
            }
            // notifies user guess is too low and displays remaining guesses.
            else
            {
                cout << "\nYour guess is too low, please try again. You have " << guessesRemaining << " guesses left.\n";
            }
        }
    }
    // notifies user of invalid input.
    else
    {
        cout << "\nDo you know how to read? Try again.\n";
    }
} while (guessesRemaining > 0); // end of do/while loop, as long as remaing guesses are more than 0

// if user doesn't guess within the 5 guesses, notifies of loss and what winning number was.
if (guessesRemaining < 1)
{
    cout << "\nWow, you suck. The number is " << randomNumber << endl << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Can you show us the loop?

Comment: I added the code. Yay! -2 votes!!

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by simply checking that the value entered is in fact an integer before using it as one. As you haven't provided a language, the general idea would be...

```
Read input into X
Check that X is in fact an integer (atoi, etc)
Use the value of X as an integer, most likely in another variable
```